# swift: tableview with images freezing

Tags: ios, swift

I have `uitableview` with 10 images in rows in my Xcode swift project. I use this code to show 10 images in rows in my `uitableview`:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "Cell0", indexPath.row), for: indexPath)


    var imageV = UIImageView()
    imageV = cell.viewWithTag(5) as! UIImageView

    imageV.image = UIImage(named:"image\(indexPath.row + 1).png")
```

But when I scroll my `uitableview` freezing very very very hard. Why is this happening? And How to fix it?

Comment: define freezing in more detail please.

Comment: @TusharSharma  freezing  when I scrolling all 10 image. But when I have already scrolled all 10 images everything is working fine.

Comment: does your image static file or downloaded from the internet?
can you offer codes about where you configure your cell

Comment: @SaiLi static file

Comment: Man, you are using 10 different cell prototypes and look at that code with images. It could be done more efficient.

Comment: You can use `UIImage(named:"image\(indexPath.row + 1).png")`

Comment: @Phyber he's using 1 cell with 10 different images, it should work without problem though, maybe the image file too large

Comment: 'String(format: "Cell0", indexPath.row)' don't change your cell's reusable identifier everytime.

Comment: @User array of 10 images will make your code look better. Keep things simple where you can.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom cell

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
}
```

In your storyboard, set the class of the cell to `MyCustomCell` and give it an identifier say `cell`.

Then, update your `cellForRow` method as below

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

    let imageName = "image\(indexPath.row + 1).png"
    cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    return cell
}
```

**UPDATE**

- Create a new swift file called `MyCustomCell.swift`
  [image]
- In storyboard, set your cell's class to `MyCustomCell`
  [image]
- Add a `UIImageView` in your cell
  [image]
- Connect the `@IBOutlet`
  [image]
- Set your cell's identifier
  [image]
- Update your `cellForRow` method
  [image]

Comment: it doesn't work. If I use 1 image for all 10 cell all works fine. But If I use 10 images scroll freezing

Comment: Have you done everything mentioned in the answer (i.e. create a custom cell, link it in storyboard and use the `cellForRow` method provided)?

Comment: I did everything as in your case but it does not work. What could be wrong?

Comment: I see that you have updated your question. You shouldn't update the question with suggestions in the answers as it confuses the next person who looks at the correspondence. Having said that, I see that you are still creating a `UIImageView` in `cellForRow` which is not what I said to do.
I'm refering to the line `var imageV = UIImageView()`. You shouldn't be creating a `UIImageView` in `cellForRow`. Instead, create it in a custom class and link the `@IBOutlet`

Comment: I think you are new to ios programming and thus not much familiar with it. Please see my updated answer for a step by step process and I would recommend to read up on some guides. You'll find a ton on the internet

Answer (score 0):

The tableview is lagging and freezing on the scrolling because of how CellForRow works. Essentially, the OS does not save cells that are displayed. For example, rows 1-2-3 are displayed on the screen and have gone through cellForRow. Rows 4 is about to be displayed and row 1 will be removed off the screen. Row 4 will go through cellForRow for it's information to be displayed, and once row 1 is off the screen it will be removed from memory. So if you then scroll back to row 1, it will go through cellForRow and reload the image. So in this case your tableview is constantly loading images from the bundle as you scroll up and down.

Your solution might be to preload all your images and have them in an array so that the OS doesn't have to spend time loading the images repeatedly. Another way to go about might be to create a custom cell and simply have the cell handle loading it's own image by providing it the image name, rather than have the tableview manage the loading of every single's cell's image repeatedly. This would also clean up your cellForRow.

For example: make a new tableViewCell called imageCell which has an imageName property that could be an String. Once the cell is made, you simply pass it the string of it's image in cellForRow, and when the imageCell is created, have it load it's own image through this string in it's awakeFromNib.

Comment: I'm sorry my experience is mostly objective-c based so I can write code in that and explain the logic. 

1. Make a global variable or a property on your class that is an Array of UIImages
2. in View Did Load, load all of your images: UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"]; for each specific image
3. Put all your images in this array: imageArray = [image1, image2, image3..., image10];
4. In CellForRow,  after dequeuing your cell do cell.imageV.image = imageArray[indexPath.row], so for row1 it will load the image at index 0 of the array etc
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "Cell0", indexPath.row), for: indexPath)
```

to

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)  as CustomCell
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourimagename")
```

**Don't change your reusable identifier everytime**. This is causing freezing in your case. Moreover create custom cell for adding **UIImage**.

Comment: Use of undeclared type 'CustomCell'

Comment: You have to create a custom class for Customcell inheriting from UITableViewCell where you will declare IBOutlet for imageView. Hope you got my point

Comment: it doesn't work. If I use 1 image for all 10 cell all works fine. But If I use 10 images scroll freezing

Comment: Yes that's what i am saying. For using single image for all 10cells, you must have single resuableidentifier for the cell then only you will be using 1image for 10cells.

Comment: I did everything as in your case but it does not work. What could be wrong?